# How do I replicate a sha256 hash with salt using OpenSSL command line?

Tags: php, encryption, openssl, hash

Using PHP's crypt function as follows, I can do a sha256 hash with salt and multiple rounds.

```
php -r "echo crypt('foo','\$5\$rounds=5000\$saltsaltsaltsalt');"
```

produces:

```
$5$rounds=5000$saltsaltsaltsalt$5RbfsOruKYb8v7hGn29A.I91maopNeJ2nIFH.SIEnSC
```

How can I perform this exact process (and/or validate a hash) using the OpenSSL command line program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This password hashing algorithm is rather complex — see the complete description: http://www.akkadia.org/drepper/SHA-crypt.txt.

Unfortunately, the `openssl passwd` command does not currently support it — there is support only for the old DES-based crypt(), MD5-based crypt() and the Apache `apr1` variant of MD5 salted hashes. There is a [Debian bug report](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=472745) requesting SHA-256/512 password hash support, but currently nothing has been done.